# How to create adaptive custom shape in wpf xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need custom shape for buttons in my wpf app. The shape needs to be like rectangle but with **45 degree** cut opposite corners like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OWpT.png). But this app will be used on different screens and button width is going to depend of container width where the button in. When width of button different to path with in xaml code the corners angle deforms like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6757.png). How can I fix it to change size only of streight lines or save button's aspect ratio when button's size is changing by container. My XAML code:

```
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                      Data="M 0 20 L 20 0 L 100 0 L 100 60 L 80 80 L 0 80 Z"
                                      Stretch="Fill">
                            </Path>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

Comment: You may bind the Data property to ActualWidth and ActualHeight by a MultiBinding with a multi-value converter the creates an appropriate Geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use transform instead of geometry:

```
<Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        BorderBrush="Blue"
        Content="HELLO WORLD">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Background="Lime"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="3,3,0,0">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-45" CenterY="50"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>

                <Border Background="LightGreen" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="3,0,0,3" 
                        Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Background="Green" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,3,3" 
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <SkewTransform AngleY="-45"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

[image: button]